# downloading csv (php, mysql) not displaying foreign characters

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have checked out other posts on this topic but have not been able to solve the issue.
The php code below is for downloading dowloading a csv of data from a db.

However there are foreign characters that are displayed as question marks (???) instead of the characters. Been trying at this for hours. would really appeciate some help on this.

Thanks

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
```

try {

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"  2.csv\""); 
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    // header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf8mb4');


$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "weddingList2-" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
fputs($f, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));


//set column headers
$fields = array('', 'name', 'phone', 'status', 'num. people');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attending";

    // GET USERS FROM DATABASE + DIRECT OUTPUT
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        $lineData = array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['phone'], $row['status'], $row['people']);
        $convertInfo = mb_convert_encoding($lineData, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
        fputcsv($f, $convertInfo, $delimiter);
    }

     //move back to beginning of file
fseek($f, 0);

//set headers to download file rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

//output all remaining data on a file pointer
fpassthru($f);
exit;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the content coming back from the database call is correctly encoded?  That would help to narrow down where the problem might lie

Comment: Also, you're serving the CSV file with a header value specifying a content encoding of UTF-8 but your content is actually UTF-16LE

Comment: @RobEyre the content is coming back correctly from the db. If I display the content it shows correctly. Also if I download a csv straight from phpMyAdmin it also displays correctly.

regarind the content encoding - I removed the UTF-8 - still not working

Comment: Whats software are you using to view that CSV?

Comment: @Jared Numbers for mac. However if I download a CSV file directly from phpMyAdmin it opens fine in Numbers

Comment: Can you view the CSV with a regular text editor and confirm there's a broken encoding in there? Additionally as mentioned above, you have a utf8->utf16 coversion. Try removing it.

Comment: I removed it. Still not working. Checked in a regular text editor - the foreign charaters still appear as question marks

Comment: Any other recommendations?